# Punctuation within quotes

Tags: punctuation, british-english, commas, quotes, speech

When I was at school I was told that a quote should end with a comma.  For example:

> "The car is on the road," said Tom.
>   "No it isn't," replied Dick.
>   "He's right — it's over there!" said Harry.

However, I've recently been advised that this is not correct, and that the preceding text should read:

> "The car is on the road." said Tom.
>   "No it isn't." replied Dick.
>   "He's right — it's over there!" said Harry.

I'm specifically interested in British English — can anyone tell me if either/both of these are correct?

EDIT

From the answers below, it seems like this depends on what follows.  For example:

> "The car is on the road," said Tom

But

> Tom said, "The car is on the road."

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned the same way you did, and have not seen anything recently to the contrary, in any reputable source. The second way you showed looks wrong. I would ask the person who advised you for a reference ("citation needed").

[This page](http://www.writersblock.ca/tips/monthtip/tipmay96.htm) says,

> A direct quotation is set off from the
>   rest of the sentence by commas. Do not
>   use a period to end a sentence quoted
>   within another sentence.

[This page](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/GRAMMAR/marks/quotation.htm) does not address the question directly, but does show by example that it endorses the style you learned in school, not the one you heard about recently.

**Update in response to edited question:**

Yes, it's correct that it depends on what follows: the period at the end of the quoted sentence is changed to a comma *only* if the containing sentence continues after the end of the quote (e.g. with a dialogue tag like "said Tom"). If the containing sentence ends with the quote, both are terminated by the same period, which is inside the quotation marks.

Btw, your example

> "The car is on the road," said Tom

is missing a final period (after `Tom`). I think this was just a typo, but I thought it worth mentioning in case that was actually part of your "Is this correct?" question.