# Proper punctuation of “John’s last words were ‘———’ ”

Tags: punctuation, commas, colons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I punctuate around quotes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/how-should-i-punctuate-around-quotes)

When attributing a quote to someone, you put a comma before the quote:

> John said, "———"

But is the comma still used in the following sentence?

> John's last words were, "———."

Or should there be something else instead? A colon maybe?

Comment: I disagree.  His question relates to adding commas after quotes that contain punctuation and his example uses the word 'ask' before the comma.  

I was wondering about comma usage after words that aren't synonymous with 'say'.

Comment: Just a quick note. Grammar is about whether you should say "John's last words were" or "is words John last". Choosing between a comma and a colon is punctuation.

Comment: Question #1560 that Matt linked to is the prototype of or target for numerous duplicate-question quote questions.  Some questions that are more in line with yours include [question #65708](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65708/punctuating-quoted-questions-in-a-parenthetical-clause), and [question #50620](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50620/using-punctuation-with-quoted-text-is-troubling), and [question #62064](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62064/including-unrelated-punctuation-in-the-quotes).

Comment: -1 Please show your research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many publishers still seem to use commas before quotations, as in your first example, but [Larry Trask](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node30.html#SECTION00091000000000000000) argued persuasively against doing so:

> A sentence containing a quotation is punctuated exactly like any other
> sentence apart from the addition of the quotation marks. You should
> not insert additional punctuation marks into the sentence merely to
> warn the reader that a quotation is coming up: that's what the
> quotation marks are for. Hence the first two of the following are bad
> style, and the third one is wrong:
>
> *President Nixon declared, "I am not a crook."
>
> *President Nixon declared: "I am not a crook."
>
> *President Nixon declared:- "I am not a crook."
>
> The comma and the colon in the first two are completely pointless,
> while the startling
> arsenal of punctuation in the third is grotesque. (Remember, a colon
> can never be followed by a hyphen or a dash.) Here is the sentence
> with proper punctuation:  President Nixon declared "I am not a crook."
> Adding more dots and squiggles to this perfectly clear sentence would
> do absolutely nothing to improve it. No punctuation mark should be
> used if it is not necessary.

‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’ largely endorses this approach, describing the comma before a quotation as an ‘older convention’.

There is even less of a need for a comma in your second example.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to vote you up, but thanks very much!  Consider me converted to comma-less quoting!

Comment: Hmm, you can certainly make a logical case that a comma before a quote adds no information to the sentence. But the convention is to include a comma, and language is all about convention and common practice. I think most English teachers would mark you wrong for omitting it.

Comment: Thank you and +1 - I am so glad to have heard this point of view.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think you should use the comma in that case, because you're treating "blahblahblah" as an object.  We can look at this as:

*John's last words were "I hid the key in the . . . ."  He then took a deep breath, and died.*

Comment: In the first sentence, the quote is a predicate nominative, referring back to "last words". Why would that justify a comma more than the second sentence? I agree with Barrie England that neither should need it, although it seems widely used.